# Visual Studio Xamarin template missing assembly references

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

### Symptoms

I've been attempting to fix my **Xamarin forms solution in Visual Studio 2017 RC1** that was generated as a **brand new template**. While **both the android and iOS sub solutions have all their .dll references properly referenced**, my UWP (Universal Windows) sub solution seems to be missing essential references to the following .dll files:

1. `'System'`
2. `'Xamarin'`
3. `'Application'`
4. `'Linq'`

I was able to locate the .dll references for `'System'` and `'System.Linq'`, in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework`, but **I'm having trouble locating the specific `'Xamarin'` reference for UWP (Windows)**. I am fairly certain finding the `'Xamarin'` reference will also resolve the `'Application'` reference as I believe it is a derivative of `'Xamarin'`.

---

### Attempted fixes

**1. Clean solution**

Result: Clean immediately cancels, errors regenerate

**2. Create new solution**

Result: No change

**3. Reinstall Visual Studio 2017 (Several times) and then create new solution**

Result: No Change

---

### Specific Error(s)

> CS0246 The type or namespace name '*-insert reference here-*' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This is happening in project platform `-solution name-.UWP` in the `App.xaml.cs` file.

Comment: Remove and re-add `Xamarin.Forms` package

Comment: @SushiHangover what is the directory for that assembly reference? You aren't referring to the Nuget package are you?

Comment: Yes, I am referring to the Nuget package, if you remove and re-add the package the references will be fixed... if you really want to hardcode the refs, look in your package directory and you will find the `Xamarin.Forms` assemblies there (by version of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the Nuget package needed to be updated.

To do this, use the "Solution Explorer" Window, right click references -> Manage NuGet Packages. A new window will pop up allowing you to update and install NuGet packages.

Alternatively, you can navigate to the Package Manager with Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution.

You can also use the package manager console and use the command: `Update-Package` to update all packages.

Comment: Same in 2015, creates projects with invalid references.  I just used the Package Manager Console, the following command reinstalls all packages; Update-Package -reinstall

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Unloaded and reloaded the UWP project and suddenly all my lost nuget references appeared (Xamarin.Forms, Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform, sqlite-net-pcl, ...)